# Плавное появление меню jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здраствуйте.
`.header`- это главная страница во весь экран. Менюшка появляется после полного скролла от главной страницы.

Нужно чтобы плавно появлялся `.menu` на **jQuery**.
**JavaScript**

```
  var menu = $('.menu');
  var limit = $('.header').height();

  function toggle(state){
    menu.toggleClass('hidden', state);

}

  $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
      if(top < limit){
        toggle(true);
      } else{
        toggle(false);
      }
  });
```

**CSS**

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height: 75px;
    background:#F8E9D6;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu.hidden{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Код работает, но нужна плавность

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужно всего лишь в css добавить `transition` и `opacity: 1`

```
.menu{
    width:100%;
    height: 75px;
    background:#F8E9D6;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .4s;
}

.menu.hidden{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, я пытался так сделать, но, к сожалению, не работает. Может нужно как-то поставить slideDown в jQuery?

Comment: @AlievA. "не работает" - то есть плавность не появилась? если так, а выше обработок никаких нет с `.menu` или с родителем блока `.menu`? можете еще html показать на всякий случай

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if($('elem').length > 0 && $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height() >= $('elem').offset().top){                                                                   
        $('elem').fadeIn();                                    
}
```